# Is there any way to configure the QR code scan & store it's data in alfresco repository

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Is alfresco content service provides support to scan the QR code in share or via any third-party tool support for it?
If yes then please share some steps to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

QR code scanning is not supported out-of-the-box. If you are trying to scan QR codes on documents you should look at scanning software that supports QA code scanning. Most modern scanning software will be able to save documents to Alfresco, either via WebDAV or CMIS.